# Seagate 3TB drive just failed, options?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, gparted

I just had a Seagate 3TB Barracuda drive fail on me. Windows cannot see the drive at all and it seems the BIOS seems to hesitate a bit when doing a SMART check, then shows all my drives except for the 3TB. There were no warnings about any issues with the drive. Ironically, this drive was a replacement for a dying hard drive a few years ago.

Windows 10 will not see the drive under any circumstances. I've tried different SATA ports, SATA power connectors, and both data and power cables. I've also booted into GParted-Live and I'm not seeing the drive anywhere.

So ultimately, my question is if anyone knows any tricks with these Seagate drive to get it going again. Just long enough for me to pull all the data off of it. I don't want to commit to a data recovery service just yet.

Comment: Try cooling the drive in the refrigerator for an hour, if you get some data off while it is still cool, put it in some ziplock bags and put in a cooler full of ice to get your data off.

Comment: Did you really rely on a ST3000DM001 for data you care about? It's [been known for some time](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/3tb-hard-drive-failure/) that this is one of the least reliable hard drives ever made!

Comment: @Moab  funny April 1 rocks

Comment: @SeanClt not funny it has worked many times for me.

Comment: @Moab's I've heard of this technique.  Rather, the variation I heard of is using a freezer overnight.  I also heard it solves a specific issue, and likely has the side effect of helping a drive start up, *once*, with even reduced likelihood of it starting up additional times thereafter.  It's a home-grown remedy that is known to have worked for many people, but is not advised as a first step, and should only be done when ready (when you have the replacement drive ready to store the data, etc.)  e.g., first we should do troubleshooting and ask if BIOS sees the drive.  Hey!  Chris!  Does BIOS...

Comment: What is goal ? Recover data or try to get this drive working ?

Comment: @SeanCit : Chris stated that.  "Just long enough for me to pull all the data off of it."

Comment: @davidschwartz yes I'm aware, just somehow I've never put it together that "I currently have one of the least reliable drives" in my computer

Comment: Guys, I have a replacement drive ready to go, I just need to bring this drive up to grab my files, then it's going out the window